# Access component variable inside SCSS file Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, sass

Is it possible to access a component variable inside `.scss` file defined for that component?
Ex:

`example.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example-selector',
  templateUrl: 'example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  @Input() size: number;
}
```

`example.component.scss`

```
.some-class {
  width: calc(100% - {{ size }};
}
```

If not, how would be a good work around?

Thanks.

Comment: no, its not possible

Comment: I will add to @Jota.Toledo 's comment that SCSS is compiled to pure CSS which is static, there is no variables.

Comment: Is there nowadays any update for this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oukei, the solution I found to work around that is actually simple and it does let you use component variables inside styles.
You basically use `[ngStyle]` directive to change the property of an element.

`example.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example-selector',
  templateUrl: 'example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  @Input() size: number;
}
```

`example.component.html`

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'width': 'calc(100% - ' + size + 'px)' }"></div>
```

or you can use calc to divide with

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'width': 'calc(100% / ' + size + ')' }"></div>
```

or use any other given property like that.
And you can also have classes defined for that element and have a specific (or multiple) properties defined with `ngStyle`.

Thanks.

Comment: The limitation of this approach is css pseudo-elements :before, :after that are not accessible in html